# Faster Convergence for Artin's Constant

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, infinite-product, constants

Artin's constant (used in his conjecture on primitive roots), is defined as

$$\mathrm{C_{Artin}} = \prod_{p \ \mathrm{primes}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\right)} = 0.3739558136\dots$$

([A005596](https://oeis.org/A005596) in the OEIS)

Are there any methods that converge faster than this?

Comment: Express your product as $e^{\log (\cdot)}$. You end up computing an infinite sum. Expanding the logs leads to the computation of sums of the form $\sum (p (p-1))^{-1}$. These can be  gotten extremely quickly with Euler-Maclaurin summation, up to very quick convergence. Putting these together isn't so bad. Cohen has written about methods such as these.

Comment: @mixedmath I am having trouble understanding. So I would do $e^{log(\sum(p(p-1))^{-1})}$, or just $\sum(p(p-1))^{-1}$? Could you explain more?

Comment: @Anonymous: The Cohen paper in the OEIS link you give explains how to compute this and other constants very quickly.

Comment: @Anonymous Also, the PARI script in the OEIS sequence computes 100 digits in milliseconds.

Comment: @Charles The Cohen link I can't use, I don't have the software to open the DVI file. And I am programming this in C++, so it doesn't have built-in calculus stuff like moebius and the prime zeta function (I do however have the normal Zeta function).